# dojo dynamic datagrid without element id

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I need to great Dojo DataGrids on-the-fly in a complex RIA app. The problem is I can't use element id's. How can I create DataGrids in javascript and then insert it into the page? Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    name: 'checkout',
    template: dojo.cache('plugins.patrons.views.templates', 'actions/checkout.html'),
    el: $('<div>'),
    store: new dojo.store.Memory({data: [{id: 1, "accession": '1000', "title": 'my book'}]}),

    initialize: function(el, data) { this.el = el; this.data = data; },

    render: function()
    {
        dojo.parser.parse(this.el.empty().html(_.template(this.template, this.data, {variable: 'data'}))[0]);
        var grid = new DataGrid({
            store: ObjectStore({objectStore: this.store}),
            structure: [
                {name:"Accession Number", field:"accession", width: "200px"},
                {name:"Title", field:"title", width: "400px"}
            ]
        }); 
        $('.checkout.action .data-grid', this.el).append(grid.domNode);
        grid.startup();
        return this;
    }
});
```

This builds the table, but you can't see it, and there's no data.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the grid an explicit height.

```
var grid = new DataGrid({
     height: 400px,
     store: ObjectStore({objectStore: this.store}),
     structure: [
            {name:"Accession Number", field:"accession", width: "200px"},
            {name:"Title", field:"title", width: "400px"}
     ]
});
```